# How do I insert an element into the header of an antdv a-drawer

Tags: vue.js, antd, drawer, antdv

How to put an element inside the header of antdv a-drawer. Vue 2.7 Composition API

```
<a-drawer
        title="TRANSCRIPT DRAWER"
        placement="bottom"
        :closable="true"
        :visible="userTranscriptsVisible"
        :get-container="false"
        @close="closeDrawer"
        :mask="false"
        wrapClassName="userTranscriptsPanel"
        :height="transcriptDrawerHeight"
      > 
        <div slot="title">
          <!-- Your content here -->
          Swag
        </div>
</a-drawer>
```

I want to put the div with swag. Inside the header portion of this. so its inline with the title "TRANSCRIPT DRAWER".

I've tried:

```
    <template slot="title">
      <div>
        <!-- Your content here -->
        Swag
      </div>
    </template>
```

and

```
        <div slot="title">
          <!-- Your content here -->
          Swag
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `title` attribute is present in the `<a-drawer>` tag properties, the slot will not take effect. You need to remove the title attribute.

and, To use the slot, you should not use `slot="title"`, but instead use:

```
<template v-slot:title>

Or

<template #title>
```